# TextField will not load from RealmSwift

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa, realm

So here is the problem that I have been going crazy with. I have an app that uses Realm as its Database. I have used Realm in the past with tableviews and it works properly. I can't seem to get the textField data that I saved to load into my view on viewDidLoad. With tableViews there is a reloadData method, but that isn't the case with textFields. I need the data that is in my data base to load into the view on viewDidLoad and I have confirmed several times that data has been saved and is sitting in the dataBase just waiting to load into the view, but it will not load.

```
import Cocoa
import RealmSwift

class PublisherViewController: NSViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var publisherName: NSTextField!    

    let realm = try! Realm()
    var pubData : Results<Pub>?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Here is where textField.stringValues should load into the viewDidLoad
        let theData = Pub()
        theData.pubName = publisherName.stringValue
        print("print \(theData)")
    }

    func save(pubData: Pub) {
        do {
            try realm.write {
                realm.add(pubData)
            }
        } catch {
            print("there was an error saving pubData \(error)")
        }
    }

    @IBAction func savePublisher(_ sender: NSButton) {
        let publisherData = Pub()
        publisherData.pubName = publisherName.stringValue
        save(pubData: publisherData)
    }
}
```

Here is my data model

```
import Foundation
import RealmSwift

class Pub: Object {
    @objc dynamic var pubName : String = """
}
```

Comment: what is `publisherName`? and where do you set the text value to your `publisherTitle`?

Comment: That was a typo sorry, The project has been edited and still yields the same results.

Comment: does theData = Pub() return any results?

Comment: So you're trying to display a saved `Pub` objects `pubName` property on the `publisherName` textfield and if the user changes the value, save the changed value to Realm?

Comment: Yes that is correct David

Comment: theData = Pub() stores data in the realm database. It returns the realm Data Object with the data in it, but it is not possible to have theData.pubName = publisherName.stringValue. I cant access the data inside the realm to assign it to the stringValue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Mrkrisher on Discord here is the answer on how to display the last saved textViews and textFields from Realm into your viewDidLoad

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    publisherName.stringValue = (pubData?.last?.pubName)?? ""
    }
```